# Combining two lists into dictionary using a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-for-loop

I have two lists:

```
headers = [Header1, Header2, Header3]
data = [(1, 'Name1'), (2, 'Name2'), (3, 'Name3'))]
```

I need to combine the lists into a dictionary into the format:

```
database = {Header1 : [1, 2, 3], Header2 : ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
```

I've tried using a nested for loop to no success, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?  It might help people get started assisting you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension with `enumerate`.

```py
headers = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
data = [(1, 'Name1'), (2, 'Name2'), (3, 'Name3')]
res = {header : [x[i] for x in data] for i, header in enumerate(headers) if i < len(data[0])}
```

Comment: what if `data[2]` is `(3, 'Name3', 'foo')`?

Comment: @JonSG In that case the question would need to clarify the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to pull out the values and then zip with the headers:

```
headers = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
data = [(1, 'Name1'), (2, 'Name2'), (3, 'Name3')]

dict(zip(headers, map(list, zip(*data))))

# {'Header1': [1, 2, 3], 'Header2': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
```

This explicitly creates lists; if you are okay with tuples, it's simpler:

```
dict(zip(headers, zip(*data)))
# {'Header1': (1, 2, 3), 'Header2': ('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def best_items(racers):
    """Given a list of racer dictionaries, return a dictionary mapping items to the number
    of times those items were picked up by racers who finished in first place.
    """
        winner_item_counts = {}
        for i in range(len(racers)):
            # The i'th racer dictionary
            racer = racers[i]
            # We're only interested in racers who finished in first
            if racer['finish'] == 1:
                for i in racer['items']:
                    # Add one to the count for this item (adding it to the dict if necessary)
                    if i not in winner_item_counts:
                        winner_item_counts[i] = 0
                    winner_item_counts[i] += 1
        
            # Data quality issues :/ Print a warning about racers with no name set. We'll take care of it later.
            if racer['name'] is None:
                print("WARNING: Encountered racer with unknown name on iteration {}/{} (racer = {})".format(
                    i+1, len(racers), racer['name'])
                     )
        return winner_item_counts
    
    
    
    
    
    sample = [
        {'name': 'Peach', 'items': ['green shell', 'banana', 'green shell',], 'finish': 3},
        {'name': 'Bowser', 'items': ['green shell',], 'finish': 1},
        {'name': None, 'items': ['mushroom',], 'finish': 2},
        {'name': 'Toad', 'items': ['green shell', 'mushroom'], 'finish': 1},
    ]
    best_items(sample)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).